# How to Find the Range of Exponential function with Parameter a as Base

Tags: functions

the function is:

```
f[x_] = a^x + Sqrt[a^x + 2]
```

````
In[357]:= Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = a^x + Sqrt[a^x + 2]
FunctionRange[{f[x], a > 0 && a != 1}, x, y]

Out[358]= a^x + Sqrt[2 + a^x]

During evaluation of In[357]:= FunctionRange::nmet: Unable to find the range with the available methods.

Out[359]= FunctionRange[{a^x + Sqrt[2 + a^x], a > 0 && a != 1}, x, y]
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = a^x + Sqrt[a^x + 2]
FunctionRange[{f[x], a > 0 && a != 1}, x, y,  Method -> {"Reduced" -> True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]